# copying photos from an I phone 4s that is not on your itunes

Tags: photos, camera

I bought a phone off E bay that had a broken screen. The person that I bought it off has asked me if I can fix it could they have the photos it had an app locker on it and have disabled that but they cannot remember what the I tunes password was so cannot access the camera role folder. Can anybody help. I need to wipe the phone as its a Christmas gift and don't want to get rid of the photos as they are all of the blokes family.

Comment: You can try importing the photo's with iPhote on a mac or with windows by going trough the files on you iPhone ( dont know how the program is called in english. In dutch it's 'windows verkenner')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [i-Funbox](http://www.i-funbox.com/ifunboxmac/) to pull photos off the iPhone. It should be easy, qbut if not, please ask.

The photos would be stored in `/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/`.

Comment: Oh cool thank you it worked perfectly I have been in such a muddle on what to do.

Comment: @will thank you! If its the right answer, please accept it as the right answer.

Comment: Um it's my first post how do I do that been looking but cant see anything that looks liker an accept button or have I got the wrong end of the stick.

Comment: @will http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @awesomebling1 thank you for all your help you are a life saver